# List.insert behavior in dart

Tags: dart

In this code snippet

```
void main() {
    List<int> myList = List.generate(2, (_) => 0, growable: true);

    myList.addAll(List<int>.generate(1, (_) => 0));

    myList.insert(3, 11);

    print(myList);
}
```

I generate a list with two elements. Then I add a list with one element to it. So in total the original list should have 3 elements. So why does an insert at index 3 (fourth element) work? I expect an out of range error as is the case with `myList.insert(4, 11)`.

Debug Code:

```
    List<int> myList = List.generate(2, (_) => null, growable: true);
    print("the list before adding temp list: ${myList}");

    myList.addAll(List<int>.generate(1, (_) => null, growable: true));
    print("the list after adding temp list: ${myList}");

    myList.insert(3, 11);
    print("the list after inserting an element at index 3 of combined list: ${myList}");
```

Debug Output:

```
the list before adding temp list: [null, null]
the list after adding temp list: [null, null, null]
the list after inserting an element at index 3 of combined list: [null, null, null, 11]
```

Comment: by that logic, position 3 isn't either. Thats the whole problem

Comment: Im defining position/index 2, not position/index 3 when i add the new list.

Comment: i added the debug output. As you can see, 
after creation: 2 elements. (indices/positions 0-1)
on adding new list: 3 elements. (indices/positions 0-2)
after List.insert: 4 elements. (indices/positions 0-3) 
Expected after List.insert(3,11): out of range

Comment: i understand (_) => null/any_other_val to insert null/any_other_val at each generated index of the list. Does it do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how `insert` works.
The index you provide is not an *element* position, but the position of a gap *between* elements - or before the first element or after the last.

So, a list of length 3 has four gaps, the `|`s of: `|1|2|3|`. These have positions 0 through 3, and you can insert an element in any of them.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand that it is a fencepost problem. Accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Move your mouse to List.generate you will see the following:

**The created list is fixed-length if [growable] is set to false.**

As you are passing true value in growable so It will increase the length of array if you will pass value False then the behavior will be changed

**growable: true, it will not throw error untill you pass invalid index for example if you write myList.insert(5, 11); without writting myList.insert(4, 11); then myList.insert(5, 11); will throw error**

```
List<int> myList = List.generate(2, (_) => 0, growable: true);

myList.addAll(List<int>.generate(1, (index) => 0));

myList.insert(3, 11); 
print(myList);
```

**growable: false It will throw error on both addAll and insert**

```
List<int> myList = List.generate(2, (_) => 0, growable: false);

myList.addAll(List<int>.generate(1, (index) => 0));

myList.insert(3, 11); 
print(myList);
```

Run the above different code you see the different behaviour.

Comment: thankyou for the answer. Does this mean when growable is true, then List.insert can add element at length+1 and not more? I would expect this to not work either. Insert should only work on available indices of a list.

Comment: List.insert can add an element at length+1 and not more?  True,  Insert should only work on available indices of a list but in Dart Insert depend on growable